# Display the console in full screen with borders, c programming

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to create a little C code, to practice, and I'm using code::blocks.

My problem: I'd like to know if there is any function in C programming that displays the console full-screen (not full-screen like video games, but full-screen like that button next to the "close window button", so full-screen with borders).

I've looked up and found a few answers to change the size of the window including this:

```
system("mode con LINES = 150, COLS = 150");
```

This solution could be enough, but because of curiosity and improvement, I wish to find a better solution.

Also, sorry for bad english.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: avez-vous cherché une bibliothèque appelée ncurses?

Comment: The values in that command can only be found through trial and error – and then they would only work for your screen size and (default) console font and font size settings.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, I haven't search for the ncurses library (gonna do it now)

Comment: On the Linux console, or xterm, printing '\L' (ASCII form feed) clears the screen, and the LINES and COLS environment variables give its dimensions. It should also work on OS X. With that information, you can redraw the screen. There is also ncurses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just needing a solution that is exclusive to Windows (as your question partially implies), this code below should work fine.  Other operating systems will likely have a different solution.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX info = {0};
    int width, height;
    HANDLE hConsole = NULL;

    // maximize window
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);

    // print width/height of this window in terms of columns and rows
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(hConsole, &info);

    width = info.srWindow.Right+1;
    height = info.srWindow.Bottom+1;
    printf("Size of this window is %d x %d\n", width, height);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it easy (enough) to retrieve the 'current' dimensions in lines and characters immediately after this command?

Comment: Yep.  Answer updated.  And welcome to Stack Overflow. If you like this answer, please "accept" it and give it the green checkbox. Additional requests should be asked as new questions.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - fixed

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
  ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow() , SW_MAXIMIZE);
```